# When transform z axis, x and y are first transformed

Tags: transforms

I have an interesting problem. When I am trying to move object along z axis, it is firstly moves along x and y, and then only z axis.
https://imgur.com/a/AXG6XTU

Can you help solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapping to surfaces is enabled. You can find its toggle at the top center of the 3D Viewport. Disable it.

[image: Snapping]

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Ростислав Романец  if the answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)